# Calculate years in service

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I made the following sql query to get a list of all employees who are 10 years in service. I'm wondering if this is the best and most efficient way to do this. For example: how can I calculate a list of all employees who are 12.5 in service?

```
DECLARE     @YEAR_CURRENT VARCHAR(4)
SET         @YEAR_CURRENT = Year(getdate())

SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    fullname, 
    CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,DATEADD(year,10,years_in_service)),105) as 'anniversary', 
    ROUND((Datediff(dd,years_in_service,isnull(@YEAR_CURRENT,getdate()))/CONVERT(FLOAT, 365)),1) AS years_in_service_today
FROM my_database
WHERE
    AND ROUND((Datediff(dd,years_in_service,isnull( @YEAR_CURRENT,getdate()))/CONVERT(FLOAT, 365)),1) >= 10
    AND ROUND((Datediff(dd,years_in_service,isnull( @YEAR_CURRENT,getdate()))/CONVERT(FLOAT, 365)),1) < 11
ORDER BY 
    fullname ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most efficient way.  A better comparison is:

```
WHERE years_in_service >= dateadd(-11, year, coalesce(@YEAR_CURRENT, getdate())) and
      years_in_service < dateadd(-10, year, coalesce(@YEAR_CURRENT, getdate()))
```

This is more efficient because it can make use of an index on `years_in_service`.  When you have a function on a column, generally an index cannot be used.

If you want 12.5 years, then change the logic to months instead of years:

```
WHERE years_in_service >= dateadd(-(12 * 12 + 6), month, coalesce(@YEAR_CURRENT, getdate())) and
      years_in_service < dateadd(-12 * 12, month, coalesce(@YEAR_CURRENT, getdate()))
```

Comment: Will `dateadd(11, year, coalesce(@YEAR_CURRENT, getdate()))` not calculate a date 11 years into the future? Was there possibly a `-` I might have overlooked?

Comment: @cars10 . .  No duh ;)  I intended for all those numbers to be negative.  (I'm mildly embarrassed by this right now.)